# Custom element numbering in Asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I would like to add a custom element to my *.adoc files that looks like:

```
remark:: Text of remark 
remark:: Text of remark 2
```

The text should be rendered like NOTE: element or similar but the remark should be numbered through the whole document, like

```
Remark 1: Text of remark 
Remark 2: Text of remark 2

...
```

Is such customizing possible in AsciiDoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using [AsciiDoc's counters](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#counters).

If you want `remark 2` and `Text of remark 2`, you may have to set a separate attribute for each.

```
:remark_count: {counter:remark}
Remark {remark_count}: Text of remark {remark_count}
:remark_count: {counter:remark}
Remark {remark_count}: Text of remark {remark_count}
```